# generate histogram in R for employee

Tags: r

Below is my dataset containing records of an employee attendance

```
         date   intime  outtime
2  02/11/2015 10:21:27 17:58:12
3  03/11/2015 10:13:09 18:52:44
4  04/11/2015 10:11:52 18:40:36
5  05/11/2015 10:31:42 18:16:57
6  06/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
10 10/11/2015 10:03:20 18:07:52
11 11/11/2015 09:40:20 18:42:20
12 12/11/2015 10:38:56 18:37:20
13 13/11/2015 10:45:26 18:09:54
16 16/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
17 17/11/2015 10:11:43 18:36:15
18 18/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
19 19/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
20 20/11/2015 12:14:25 20:25:08
23 23/11/2015 10:08:08 17:57:35
24 24/11/2015 14:30:32 18:36:15
```

The total time served by employee in hours is :

```
total_time <- with(newdata, sum(pmin(newdata$outtime, "18:00:00") - 
                                pmax(newdata$intime, "08:00:00")   ))
total_time <- 24*floor(as.numeric(total_time))
"Total time served by employee is : 96 hours"
```

I want to generate histogram for each employee showing hours served on monthly basis having a total of 5 bins.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share data when using the `r` tag. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `hist()`? Another route may be `barplot()`.

Comment: Yes i have tried but cant make it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the data such that we had info for more months: ( for a better histogram)

```
library(data.table)
df = fread("    date   intime  outtime
           02/11/2015 10:21:27 17:58:12
           03/11/2015 10:13:09 18:52:44
           04/11/2015 10:11:52 18:40:36
           05/11/2015 10:31:42 18:16:57
           06/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
           10/11/2015 10:03:20 18:07:52
           11/11/2015 09:40:20 18:42:20
           12/11/2015 10:38:56 18:37:20
           13/11/2015 10:45:26 18:09:54
           16/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
           17/11/2015 10:11:43 18:36:15
           18/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
           19/11/2015 10:13:13 18:36:15
           20/11/2015 12:14:25 20:25:08
           23/11/2015 10:08:08 17:57:35
           24/11/2015 14:30:32 18:36:15")

 df$intime <- as.POSIXct(df$intime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
 df$outtime <- as.POSIXct(df$outtime, format = "%H:%M:%S")

library(lubridate) #to extract the day
df$day <- dmy(df$date)
df$day <- day(df$day)

df$total_time <- difftime(pmin(df$outtime, as.POSIXct("18:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")), 
                       pmax(df$intime, as.POSIXct("08:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")), units = "hours")
df$total_time <- as.numeric(df$total_time)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y= total_time))+geom_histogram(stat = "identity", bins = 5)
```

[image: op]

---

with just 5 bins (only 4 bins appear in the plot because no data for 24-30 day's intervals) :

```
df$breaks <- cut(df$day, breaks = c(0,5,10,15,30,max(df$day)))
df1=ddply(df, "breaks", summarise, "total_hr"=sum(total_time))
ggplot(df1, aes(x = breaks, y= total_hr))+
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity", bins = 5, binwidth = 0)
```

[image: op]

Comment: I wanted histogram for one month only :)

Comment: huh!!! ohhh :(   total hours for each employee? how do yo differentiate the employee? additional columns for that?

Comment: or do you want the hours on x-axis?

Comment: hours will be on y-axis and days of the month will be on x-axis. days can be grouped into 5 and histogram can be of 5 bins. got my point ? :) 
please help

Comment: i have tried from my side....hope this answers you or atleast gives you a start! kindly accept if this has answered your question

Comment: Thankyou :) it was a great help :)

Comment: Can you please explain this logic to me ? it worked perfectly but if you can please explain :)

Comment: the logic of? I simply called the ggplot histogram functions ! to get the bins, used cut() which divides into bins according to how many you want. ?cut would help you out!